# finding distribution of words in R

Tags: r

I want to find the distribution of number of titles with 1 word, 2 words, 3 words, ... in my dataset "jnl.dt" in R.

```
one_word_title = 0
two_word_title = 0
three_word_title = 0
for (i in 1:x){
  if (str_count(jnl.dt[i]$`Full Title`, '\\w+')==1){one_word_title <- one_word_title+1}
  else if (str_count(jnl.dt[i]$`Full Title`, '\\w+')==2){two_word_title <- two_word_title+1}
  else if (str_count(jnl.dt[i]$`Full Title`, '\\w+')==3){three_word_title <- three_word_title+1}
}
one_word_title
two_word_title 
three_word_title
```

Is there a way to find the distribution of number of titles with different number of words without hardcoding the number of words in title?

Comment: Something like `jnl.dt %>% mutate(WordCount=str_count(` `Full Title` `)) %>% group_by(WordCount) %>% summarise(NumberOfTitles=n(), .groups="drop")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this for every word separately, you can do this together.

```
table(stringr::str_count(jnl.dt$`Full Title`, '\\w+'))
```

Comment: thank you! that was so simple wow

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proposal somewhat tentative given the absence of reproducible data:

Let's assume you have this kind of data and `titles`:

```
df <- data.frame(titles = c("The Great Gatsby", "That's the Story of my Life", "Love Story", "Alice in Wonderland", "Harry Potter"))
```

To get the "distribution" of number of words in the `titles`you can do this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
  mutate(N_w = str_count(titles, "\\S+")) %>%
  group_by(N_w) %>% 
  summarise(Dist_N_w = n())
# A tibble: 3 x 2
    N_w Dist_N_w
* <int>    <int>
1     2        2
2     3        2
3     6        1
```

Note that using `\\w+` and, respectively, `\\S+` makes a difference: as the apostrophe is not contained in the `\\w` character class (for letter, digits, and the underscore) `That's` will be counted as 2 words. If you use `\\S` instead, which is a negative character class matching anything that is a whitespace (including actual whitespace and also new line and return characters etc.), the count for `That's`  will be 1.

Comment: that's a good point! thank you for your help :)

Comment: If it helped pls consider upvoting it.

Answer (score 0):

We may use `unnest_tokens`

```
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
    unnest_tokens(word, titles) %>% 
    count(rn) %>%
    count(n)
```